# invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c++

while solving a question on hackerearth i got this error , i tried to find solution but everywhere this error occurs when 2 different datatypes are used as operands but in my case both the operands  of sama data type, here is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[1000];
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    double ans=1;
    for(int i =0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
        ans=(ans*arr[i])%(pow(10,9)+7);
    }
    cout << ans;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the expected output of `12.3 % 4.2` ?
If you have an answer for that, you also have to roll your own implementation, built in `operator%` works for integer types only.

If you are fine with that, but your arguments happen to be floating point values, round/floow/ceil/cast them. e.g:

```
static_cast<uint64_t>(double_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Module operator (i.e. `operator%`) is not defined for floating points, but for integers only.

As you declared `ans` as a double, your expression `ans*arr[i]` evaluates as a double. Changing it to `int ans` will have the erroneous statement to compile (actually returning the integer modulo).