# error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%

Tags: c++, debugging, double, height, calculator

I've been making a Height prediction calculator but i have been given an error when compiling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int i = 0;
  do {
    double mom;
    double dad;
    string boygirl;
    double fullboy = (mom * 13 / 12 + dad) / 2;
    double fullgirl = (dad + 12 / 13 + mom) / 2;
    double twsub = 12;
    double twsub2 = 12;

    cout << " \n\nWELCOME TO THE C++ HEIGHT PREDICTION PROGRAM";
    cout << "\n\n INPUT GENDER TO BEGIN boy/girl: ";
    cin >> boygirl;

    cout << "How tall is your mother in inches: ";
    cin >> mom;
    cout << "How tall is your father in inches: ";
    cin >> dad;

    if (boygirl == "boy") {
      cout << fullboy % twsub2 << "ft"
           << "is your estimated height";
    }

    else if (boygirl == "girl") {
      cout << fullgirl % twsub << "ft"
           << " is your estimated height";
    }

    ++i;
  } while (i < 10);
}
```

The error is

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%
```

It happens when it goes through these lines of code:

```
if (boygirl == "boy") {
    cout << fullboy % twsub2 << "ft" << "is your estimated height";
}
```

and

```
else if (boygirl == "girl") {
  cout << fullgirl % twsub << "ft" << " is your estimated height";
}
```

I was wondering if anybody could help me fix this error in my code

Thank you

Comment: Modulos operator is only defined for integral types, for floating point you can use `fmod()`

Comment: can you give me an example of what it would look like in my code?

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove almost all of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: `#include <cmath>` and `cout << std::fmod(fullgirl, twsub) << "ft"...`

Comment: lets see if it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167199/invalid-operands-of-types-double-and-double-to-binary-operator)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use modulos operator `%` only on integral types like `int`. For floating point types like `double` you can use a function [`std::fmod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) which is provided by standard library:

```
std::cout << std::fmod( fullboy, twsub2 ) << "ft is your estimated height";
```

Note you have also issues with integer division in this code:

```
double fullgirl = (dad + 12 / 13 + mom) / 2;
```

it should be something like:

```
double fullgirl = (dad + 12.0 / 13.0 + mom) / 2.0;
```

though in this line you do not have such issue:

```
double fullboy = (mom * 13 / 12 + dad) / 2;
```

it is better to do it everywhere as a good habit to prevent errors. Details can be found here [Why does this calculation (division) return a wrong result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827246/why-does-this-calculation-division-return-a-wrong-result)